# Cache non entity query output from spring jpa using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching

I am trying to Cache List coming as a result from my Student table, but somehow it is not caching the results and everytime hitting to the database.

Please note: if i am query the whole Student Entity caching is working, but not working from the custom query output.

It seems like a very common case,  I have already tried adding @Cacheable and also tried @QueryHints, but no luck.

```java
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM Student")
    @Cacheable(value = "distinctName")
    @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"))
    List<String> getDistinctNames();
```

Please also suggest what is the best way to populate list of student names in a UI dropdown with server side caching

Comment: Are you using Java EE or Spring?

Comment: Springboot JPA.

Comment: Have you added @EnableCaching to your SpringBootApplication a Configuration class?

Comment: have u found the solution?